# Typescript / TSLint : how to call typeof on function return value?

Tags: typescript, tslint

This works fine:

```
const f = () => ({
  a: 5,
  b: "hi",
  c: true
});

const a = f();

type t = typeof a;  // t is {a: number, b: string, c: boolean}
```

But this does not work:

```
const f = () => ({
  a: 5,
  b: "hi",
  c: true
});

type t = typeof (f());  // TSLint error: "Identifier expected"
```

Why doesn't this work? Any idea how to define t without having to create a?

Comment: It works fine, Issue is for keyword `type` http://jsfiddle.net/zwm0vtpy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ReturnType` conditional type to get the return type of the function

```
const f = () => ({
  a: 5,
  b: "hi",
  c: true
});

type t = ReturnType<typeof f>;  // t is {a: number, b: string, c: boolean }
```